# Ошибка Three.js Uncaught TypeError : Failed to resolve module specifier и т.д

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

Всем здравствуйте!

Пытаюсь добавить на сайт 3д модель формата gbl,вот код js :

```
 import * as THREE from './three.js-master/build/three.module.js'
import {GLTFLoader} from './three.js-master/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js'

const canvas = document.querySelector('.webg1')
const scene = new THREE.Scene()

const loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader()
loader.load('/img/ROLLS2.glb', function(glb){
    console.log(glb)
    const root = glb.scene;
    root.scale.set(0.1, 0.5, 0.5)
    scene.add(root);
}, function(xhr){
    console.log((xhr.loaded/xhr.total * 100) + "% loaded")

}, function(error){
    console.log('An error occured')
})

const light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1)
light.position.set(2,2,5)
scene.add(light)


const sizes = {
    width: window.innerWidth,
    height: window.innerHeight
}

const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, sizes.width/sizes.height, 0.1, 100)
camera.position.set(0,1,2)
scene.add(camera)

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    canvas: canvas
})

renderer.setSize(sizes.width, sizes.height)
renderer.setPixelRatio(Math.min(window.devicePixelRatio, 2))
renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true
renderer.gammaOuput = true

function animate(){
    requestAnimationFrame(animate)
    renderer.render(scene, camera)
}

animate()
```

Появлятся вот такая ошибка :
[image: ошибка]

Uncaught TypeError : Failed to resolve module specifier '/sites/obespechen/#:1' "three".Relative references must start with either '/', './' or '../'

Не понимаю,в чём ошибка?Я же всё правильно написал

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Данная ошибка возникает при использовании импортов предназначенных для `Node.js` в браузере. Дело в том что хотя они и выглядят одинаково, но в браузере они работают иначе и требуют относительного пути.

В конкретном случае "ошибка" если так можно это назвать не в написанном коде, а чуть глубже. Дело в том что при импорте происходит не только импорт указанных файлов, но и все импорты указанные в них и так далее т.е. импорт всего дерева импортов.

Поэтому когда файл `GLTFLoader.js`делает внутри себя импорт:

```
import {
    AnimationClip,
    Bone,
    ... 
    sRGBEncoding
} from 'three';
```

происходит ошибка ведь как написано в сообщении об ошибке ожидается относительный путь а тут просто `'three'`

**Быстрое решение:**

Чтобы решить эту задачу максимально быстро нужно скопировать файл `GLTFLoader.js` в папку `build`где уже лежит файл `three.module.js` а далее поменять импорт (65 строка в файле  GLTFLoader.js) на соответсвующий с `'tree'` на `'./three.module.js'` после этого ошибка пропадет. Если понадобятся еще другие модули то с ними нужно будет проделывать эту же процедуру.

Так же хочу заметить, что если Вы клонировали или скачивали репозиторий https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js  то Вам нет необходимости иметь все его содержимое, достаточно папки `build` ее можно переименовать к примеру в `vendor` (типичное название таких папок) и поместить рядом с html файлом, разумеется импорты тогда будут короче:

```
import * as THREE from './vendor/three.module.js'
import {GLTFLoader} from './vendor/GLTFLoader.js'
```

В качестве доказательства, что это решение правильное я нашел старый код где применяется `cdn`

```
  <script type="module">
    import * as THREE from 'https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/threejs/r122/build/three.module.js';
    import {OrbitControls} from 'https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/threejs/r122/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js';
    import {GLTFLoader} from 'https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/threejs/r122/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js';
```

если открыть файл https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/threejs/r122/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js импортируемый тут, то мы увидим такой же относительный путь `"../../../build/three.module.js"`  в данном случае он чуть более глубок, лишь потому что они не переносили файл в папку `build` в остальном принцип тот же.

Подводя итоги, выскажу свое мое мнение - использование сборщика бандлов таких как [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) или [Rollup](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/) не дает шансов подобным вопросам  возникнуть. Мы просто устанавливаем нужный нам пакет через `npm` или `yarn` и далее настроив сборщик бандлов конфигом собираем проект, во время сборки ссылки разрешаются автоматическим образом.

**Решение с WEBPACK:**

1. создаем папку проекта
2. запускаем `npm init -y` (создание дефолтного package.json)
3. `npm i three`
4. `npm i --save-dev @types/three` (модуль для путей в импортах)
5. `npm install --save-dev webpack`
6. `npm install webpack webpack-cli --save-dev` (консольный инструмент)
7. `npm install --save-dev path` (модуль используется в конфиге )
8. создаем в корневой папке `конфиг вебпака`:

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './main.js', // какой файл собираем
  output: { // куда поместим
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'), // путь
    filename: 'main.js', // какое будет имя бандла
  },
};
```

9. создаем `html` файл в корне папки:

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Пример Treejs + Webpack</title>
  <script type="module" src="dist/main.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

10. создаем файл с кодом

**main.js**

```
import * as THREE from 'three';
import {GLTFLoader} from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader';
и далее наш код
```

11. в `package.json` добавляем скрипт билда

**! не забываем** поставить запятую в конце строки с `"test"`

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
  "build": "webpack"
},
```

12. после этого мы можем запустить в консоли команду:

```
npm run build
```

Теперь открывая нашу страницу через `Live Server` локально мы увидим работающий код

**Решение с ROLLUP:**

Это решение может быть проще если воспользоваться [стартовым проектом](https://github.com/rollup/rollup-starter-app) указанным в их [документации](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#quick-start) все что нужно:

1. клонировать этот проект или скачать архивом и распаковать
2. `npm i three`
3. `npm i --save-dev @types/three` (модуль для путей в импортах)
4. в файле `main.js` удалить весь код и добавить наш, **импорты будут выглядеть немного иначе** (добавится '.js' во втором)

**main.js**

```
import * as THREE from 'three';
import {GLTFLoader} from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js';
// далее наш код
```

5. `npm run build` как и в случае с вебпаком соберет проект.

**Важно**: файл модели в этом случае нужно разместить в папке `public`

Comment: ,можете помочь с этим вопросом https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1475313/522496

Comment: Данил вы бы очень помогли бы мне)